How to get a report from some fields of two tables with a many-to-many relationship and display the data in the report table
I have two tables (patient and radiography) and an intermediate table between these two tables, the relationship between the two tables is many-to-many, and I want to enter some fields of the first and second tables into the intermediate table and get reports from the two tables.
But I don't know how to do this so that after registering the information in the first and second table, the third table is filled automatically
You can see these codes below:
class Patient(Base):
    __tablename__="Patient"
    ptn_Id=Column(Integer, primary-key= True)
    Name=Column(NVARCHAR)
    Family=Column(NVARCHAR)
    Age=Column(NVARCHAR)
    Weight=Column(NVARCHAR)

class RdioGraphy(Base):
    __tablename__="RdioGraphy"
    GId=Column(Integer, primary-key= True)
    G_Sinus=Column(NVARCHAR)
    G_Skull=Column(NVARCHAR)
    G_Chest=Column(NVARCHAR)
    G_Ribs=Column(NVARCHAR)

patient_RdioGraphy=Table("Ptn_Gph",Base.metadata,
    Column("Patient_Id",Integer,ForeignKey("Patient.ptn_Id")),
    Column("Graphy_Id",Integer,ForeignKey("RdioGraphy.GId"))
          )

I was trying to access Id of tables with this query but I didn't get anything!
def ReadByQuery(self,patient_RdioGraphy,Patient,Graphy):
result = session.query(Patient, Graphy).join(patient_RdioGraphy).filter( Patient.ptn_Id ==
patient_RdioGraphy.Patient_Id).filter(Graphy.GId == patient_RdioGraphy.Graphy_Id).all()
return result
Ireally confused and I don't know what should I do?
